# Ruby Mechanize - create custom "Submit" button

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Would it be possible to create a new "submit" button inside an existing form, with a custom "name" attribute and then submit it?

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking. Mechanize relies on Nokogiri, which *can* modify the HTML, but Mechanize might not be able to recognize that change without reparsing. But, more important, the server-side will not be able to accept the changed form unless it's been written to handle unexpected/arbitrary submit field names. I'd highly recommend learning more about how web-servers and form-processing works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it's probably easier to just do:

```
form['custom_name'] = value
```

And then submit it.